# Linux Dialog Input Box Problems

Tags: linux, bash, dialog, ncurses

I'm having a issue with the input-box on dialog. It is overlaying the text that was typed when enter is pressed. This happens wherever the cursor focus is when enter is pressed.

This is the code im using it is bash

```
OUTPUT="INPUT.txt"
>$OUTPUT

dialog --stdout --title "Client Name" \
--backtitle "Setup" \
--inputbox "Enter The Client Name" 0 0 2>$OUTPUT
CLIENTNAME=$(<$OUTPUT)
rm $OUTPUT
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't happens in here. What are your _bash_ and _dialog_ versions?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), cdialog (ComeOn Dialog!) version 1.1-20120215

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: i have a long script that sets up server but the input box doesnt look correct, everything else works. I just want it to look properly. See picture above

Comment: Yeah, now I've fully understood it. Check my answer below (=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `--stdout` option, but redirecting *STDERR* instead of *STDOUT*.

Change

```
--inputbox "Enter The Client Name" 0 0 2>$OUTPUT
```

To

```
--inputbox "Enter The Client Name" 0 0 >$OUTPUT
```

That will fix it when using `--stdout`.